# Parse JSON link in Objective C

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json, parsing

I`m building an app for iPad. Can anybody give me any advice on how to parse this JSON link in Objective C, so I can get an image (media_655fa.png) from "item_media"?  Example code:

```
{
  "id":"6",
  "item_type":"page",
  item_name":"intro_page",
  "item_media":"http:\/\/demo.test.biz\/test\/var\/uploads\/default_item\/media_655fa.png",
  "item_text":""
}
```

Or, if anybody has some advice on how to do it. The problem is in the link that PHP sends with `json_encode()`. How can I do it in objective C like `json_decode` or `regexp` in PHP?

Comment: Have a look at NSJSONSerialization ...

Comment: Yes. The link is the problem with weird two \/.. :-(

Comment: If you already use NSJSONSerialization then you should mention that and show your code. - The \\/ looks more like a server side error to me.

Comment: Thanks to editors for helping me to show the code.. :-)

Comment: Sorry type error the problem is in parsing (\/)

Comment: Have you tried the following?: Your JSON is an `NSDictionary` and called let's say `jsonDict`. Do `NSString *cleanLink = [jsonDict[@"item_media"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@""];`

Comment: @HAS: NSJSONSerialization should already "unescape" `\/` to `/`. - But there is some confusion because the question was edited several times :-)

Comment: Sorry for editing so much... I try to make question understandable... the main thing is to get the image which is generated over json_encode() function on the server. It`s dynamic use from server to iOS app

Comment: Simple (stupid) question:  Do you understand what the `\/` pattern is?  It is an "escaped" `/`, to indicate that the `/` is not "significant" to some intervening protocol, such as HTML.  Generally, a JSON deserializer should un-escape such sequences, but if not they can be easily fixed, before or after deserialization, using `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString;` or some such.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse json as :

```
// ***************** FETCHING DATA  ******************* //
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",SiteAPIURL]];
NSData *data= [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL];
if (data == nil) {
    return;
}
NSError* error;
NSMutableDictionary *jsonIs = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData:data
                          options:kNilOptions
                          error:&error];

// NSLog(@"Json : %@",jsonIs);
if (jsonIs != nil) {

        NSString *item_media = [jsonIs objectForKey:@"item_media"];
}
```

Here `item_media` is your image link.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that PHP is sending data over json_encode() function?

Comment: Ya this should be fix at PHP end.

Comment: Do not use `dataWithContentsOfURL:` when fetching data from a remote server. Instead use NSURLConnection and implement the asynchronous pattern with a NSURLConnectionDelegate. You'll find more help on SO on how to accomplish this. With the former method, you cannot check error codes, can't set HTTP headers, can't cancel the connection etc. You all require this when fetching data from a server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSString *jsonString = @"{\"id\":\"6\",\"item_type\":\"page\",\"item_name\":\"intro_page\",\"item_media\":\"http://demo.test.biz/test/var/uploads/default_item/media_655fa.png\",\"item_text\":\"\"}"; // Here jsonString is your Response from server

NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

__autoreleasing NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

if(jsonDictionary != nil) {

    NSLog(@"~~~~ item_media: %@", [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"item_media"]);
}
```

Comment: Note that the correct way to check for success is `if (jsonDictionary != nil)`, not `if (error == nil)`.

Comment: If any parsing error, error will not be nil. So that we are passing a reference of error to JSONSerializer

Comment: Read this comment from NSJSONSerialization.h ok?

/* Create a Foundation object from JSON data. Set the NSJSONReadingAllowFragments option if the parser should allow top-level objects that are not an NSArray or NSDictionary. Setting the NSJSONReadingMutableContainers option will make the parser generate mutable NSArrays and NSDictionaries. Setting the NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves option will make the parser generate mutable NSString objects. If an error occurs during the parse, then the error parameter will be set and the result will be nil.*/

Comment: @AugustinePA: It is not guaranteed that `error == nil` if *no error* occurs, therefore checking the return value is the correct way. - See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/9945060/1187415.

Comment: So Apples document is not true. Can u suggest me one test case when error will not set if parsing error occurred?

Comment: @AugustinePA: The Apple documentation *is* correct. If an error occurred then `error` will be set. But if *no error occurred*, then `error` *could* also be set to something.